# Proving if two planes are coincident

Tags: vector-spaces

How would I prove if the two planes below are coincident or not?

$x+2y-5z=1$

$2x-3y+z=3$

Do I need to prove that one equation can equal the other?

Comment: They are not as both have different set of solutions

Comment: Two planes are coincident iff they have infinite solutions.

Comment: @HarshalGajjar Two planes can meet in a line, which has an infinite number of points. In most of the spaces we are interested in it is impossible for two planes to meet in a non-zero finite number of points.

Comment: @MarkBennet Oh sorry, to correct: two planes are coincident iff the have infinite solutions with varying x,y,z. Pls correct if wrong. :)

Comment: Also, @MarkBennet For only two planes: will only the ratio(s) of constants and coefficients decide whether the planes are coincident?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $(0,0,3)$ belongs to the second plane, but not the first, as $0+2\times 0-5 \times 3=-15$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of coincident planes: The ratio of coefficient of respective variable$(x,y,z)$ must be all equal.Also this ratio should be equal to ratio of constant terms. In short, one of the equation of plane should be equal to some constant times the other equation .
In your question the 2 planes are not coincident.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_{1}: x+2y-5z=1$ and

$P_{2}: 2x-3y+z=3$

You can rewrite the plane equations in their vectorial form, i.e.

$P_{1}: (1,2,-5) \cdot (x-1,y,z)=0$;

$P_{2}: (2,-3,1) \cdot (x,y,z-3)=0$

Note that $(1,2,-5)$  and $(2,-3,1)$ are linearly independent, so the planes will not be parallel, then there's an intersection between them, given by the line wich its direction vector is $(1,2,-5) \times (2,-3,1)$

Answer (score 0):

The normals are $(1,2,-5)$ and $(2,-3,1)$.  These aren't parallel,  so neither are the planes and they meet in a line.

If by coincident you meant the same plane,   then you just need to check if one equation is a multiple of the other.  The answer is no.  (Of course if they were, then the normals would be multiples of each other as well).